# Not known - Yes - No Buttons

Tags: forms, buttons

Imagine a form with a list of items (facilities - toilets, showers, etc.) where for each of them user can select whether the item exists (Yes), doesn't exist (No) or it's not known whether it exists (Not known). What would be the best way to present this to the user?

I'm looking for a solution that is graphically pleasing, intuitive and user friendly. My initial idea was to simulate a three-position switch with labels above to indicate the selection. I will appreciate links to existing solutions or simply verbal ideas.

**Update**

Based on your suggestions, I've decided for the following design. Thank you all for your answers.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTFHne.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without knowing the use case, this is a little difficult to answer. For instance, what is the motivation of the user filling out this form? Are they doing it because they want to, or because they have to? Is it a survey, where you just want to see what people know, or is accuracy of paramount importance?

I would not **not** recommend a three-position switch, as the custom GUI element is likely to confuse the user (you'd be surprised how many people are still confused about the iOS UISwitch, even after 6 years on the market). Instead, I'd look to well-designed survey forms to inspire you here: one row per item, with three mutually exclusive radio buttons per line:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5FvXV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

You could also use a similar layout, but use three segment buttons, instead:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6E7M0.png)</sup>

Or, if the context is one of quick action, you could present each question individually. For instance, the Gas Buddy app has recently begun asking about other features of gas stations after a user reports prices, via a single-question popup overlay (with the question followed by individual buttons for 'Yes', 'No', and 'I Don't Know'.

Comment: It might be a bit confusing to have check-boxes in that table. Is there any hint to let me know I can't check also No column for the first row? Same problem with buttons.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, they were meant to be radio buttons... I'll update my mockup. Segmented controls infer mutual exclusion, though.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you.  BTW, it looks like my answer repeats yours a bit. Do you want me to remove it?

Comment: @RenatGilmanov Nah, your alternate renderings of radio buttons are quite nice.

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because I like the three segments button suggestion (I think I'll use the question mark symbol instead of "I don't know"). All answers were inspiring though so thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You need to make a clear statement saying only one state can be selected for an item. Group of radio buttons or three state switch will do the trick.

> A radio button or option button is a type of graphical user interface
>   element that allows the user to choose only one of a predefined set of
>   options.

Something like the following:

[image]

Comment: The only negative I can see to your first example is that it has grouped the radio buttons in columns. It sort of suggests that you select one item in each column, rather than per row.

Comment: Your second suggestion is something I had in mind at first. It isn't clear from my question though (my bad) that not all items will have the three-state button as an option. That is ultimately the reason why I favour the three segments button from the chosen answer.

Answer (score 7):

Agree with the radios-based answers above, except the controls themselves need to convey the meaning, so users don't have to keep in mind the titles of the columns. Similar to what Daniel has suggested, but maybe in a more graphic way.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0JsDp.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

One possible options would be to use three lists:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv6Hu9.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Although it would be necessary to explain to the user what they had to do.

Comment: This would be clumsy for a short list, but could be a big time saver if the list is very long.  +1 for a good solution for that niche, if not likely for most situations.

Comment: So you need to click twice instead of once for every item (select+button). And if you want to change an item from Exists to something else, you need to click it in the Exists column and the buttons would shift over and change to "<<Doesn't exist" and "<Unknown"? And if you need to look up an item you need to scan all three lists? I think that this is overcomplicating a simple control...